# Create Classes based on Field Values using Python in the Field Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, field-calculator, classification, python-parser

I'm using ArcGIS 10.3 and I want to create classes (1-4) in a field called "Util_Class" based on the values of a field called "OverallUtil". I think I have syntax error and have been entering this into the Field Calculator:

```
def Reclass (!Util_Class!):
  if (!OverallUtil! <= 0.6):
    return 1
  elif ( !OverallUtil!>0.6 and !OverallUtil!<= 0.75):
    return 2
  elif ( !OverallUtil!>0.75 and !OverallUtil!<=0.90):
    return 3
  elif (!OverallUtil! > 0.90):
    return 4
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the **Codeblock** - see above your code box there's a button that says "Show Codeblock".  Check that, and you can enter your code into the codeblock.

```
def myReclass(overallUtil):
  if (overallUtil <= 0.6):
    return 1
  elif (overallUtil > 0.6 and overallUtil <= 0.75):
    return 2
  elif (overallUtil > 0.75 and overallUtil <=0.90):
    return 3
  elif (overallUtil > 0.90):
    return 4
```

and in the expression box below it enter

```
myReclass(!OverallUtil!)
```

**Note** I have made a couple of changes to your code